# Unable to create new native thread even when I am not hitting any known limits

Tags: multithreading, out-of-memory, limit

I am hitting exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread. To replicate this, I run a basic program on the machine which just creates threads:

Program:

```
int count=0;
while(true){
    count++;
    System.out.println(count);
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000000);
            } catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I consistently hit the exception at ~12240 threads. This is not close to any of the known limits which I have tried and also changed some.
These are some of the limits:

```
ulimit -u
451140

kernel.pid_max = 4194304
 
 cat /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
10000000
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
902281

~# vi /etc/systemd/system.conf
defaultTasksMax == changed to unlimited
```

I need help to understand which Limit am I reaching and how to increase the thread count.

Comment: Perhaps you are simply running out of memory? Doesn't JVM (by default) use something like 1mb of stack size for each thread?

Comment: I never reach my memory limits too, I am only utilizing 50% of the total memory available. yes default is 1 mb for stack size, but I have 110 GB Ram avaialble

Comment: Depending on the platform JVM may actually use only 50% of available memory (see this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1035652 although I'm not entirely sure if this is your case). That would correlate well with your observation.

Comment: The limits mentioned are for java heap space but that shouldn't have much impact on the thread experiment I did.

Comment: Well, this is not clear, but in reality there is no difference between stack and heap. Its just memory. Once a thread is created it has to put its stack somewhere, right? That somewhere is just heap. Of course this is my guess, I don't really know internals of JVM.